# using EWS differences beetwen with Exchange 2010 server and Exchange 2007 server

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server

I 'm using EWS to cominicate with Exchange Servers both 2010 and 2007...
There is a versionning property for ExchangeServerBinding object.
I googled but found out any critical differences while EWS working with Exchange2010 and Exchange2007..

So is there any differences while accessing Exchange2010 and Exchange2007 with EWS?

Answer (score 4):

If you talk to exchange 2010 with 2007's wsdl - no differences at all.

If you talk to exchange 2007 with 2010's wsdl it works pretty fine as well, however you should be careful not to use 2010 specific methods/properties. EWS 2010 introduces new functionality like associated items you can't use from 2007

Comment: also of note is that the feature set for EWS is different between Exchange 2007 and Exchange 2007 sp1

Comment: True, however you can point out in the product's requirements that SP1 is required. Updating to SP1 isn't complicated at all, and most probably admins will alredy have it installed if they care about security. This is not like updating from 2003 to 2010. Our service for example will simply shutdown if non SP1 of 2007 detected.

Comment: I mentioned it just as a potential pitfall, since the EWS feature is different.  As one of my clients JUST upgraded to SP1 2007 SP1 this year.  Though I do agree with you in that it isn't as major an upgrade.